# OpenID Connection session management - can ID token be revoked?

Tags: access-token, jwt, openid-connect

In OpenID Connect, the ID token is a cryptographically signed, self-contained token which allows resource owners to authorize access without a call to the authorization server. So, if the Authorization server isn't necessary to validate the token, how can it be revoked in a session management scenario? It seems like the only thing that can be revoked is the refresh token at which point the ID token would just expire and the user would have to reauthenticate. Is this correct? Also, does it even make sense for OpenID Connect Provider/Server to store the token at all as it hands it off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `id_token` cannot be explicitly revoked because of the reasons that you mention: it is self-contained and can be used without dependency on the Provider. However, a typical usage in web applications is to use the `id_token` upon receipt to create an application session, store the relevant information from the `id_token` in the session and then to discard the `id_token` itself. That application session can be terminated upon request from the Provider by implementing the OpenID Connect Session Management extension, see: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html. In this web SSO use case the `id_token` lifetime would be limited since it is one-time usage only.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Just so I understand the whole picture, in a typical single-page app scenario, id token is used to retrieve user information and create a client-side session. Access token, which is another token returned from the token endpoint, is used to authorize access to protected API resources. Is this correct? Does the client app need to be able to verify the id token? Check if it's expired? I'm assuming it doesn't need to verify the token as long as the issuer is trusted. But it probably needs to make sure it hasn't expired and if it has use refresh token to new it up?

Comment: I'd wager that the same expiration check needs to be made for access token and id token on every request for protected API resource. And if either one expires, renew both with a refresh token.

Comment: one cannot get a new `id_token` using the `refresh_token` because the semantics of the `id_token` require that the user is present/authenticated i.e. the user must be involved; a new authentication request to the Provider is the way to go; at the Provider an SSO session may still exist in which case the new `id_token` is generated without explicit user interaction